# How to access value of array of dictionaries of dictionaries of array at index?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have an array that holds dictionaries whose value is an array of dictionary whose value is an array of strings. Each key of each the dictionary is a String. the structure is like so:

```
[String : [String : [String]]]
```

I am trying to get the value of the array at the index like so:

```
for index in 0...arrayCount {
    let thisValue = myArray[index]
}
```

where myArray represents the array of dictionaries in question.
However, I get the error message:

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : [String : [String]]]' with an index of type 'Int'

I would think that saying let thisValue = myArray[index] would assign thisValue to be a dictionary of the form String : [String : [String]]

Can anyone explain I might be doing incorrectly and how I can access the value at index?

Comment: You don't have an array of dictionary of array of dictionary of array. You have a dictionary of dictionary of array.

Comment: Your outer most data structure is a dictionary rather than an array as rmaddy said. Posting a bit more information with concrete variables may help.

Comment: Possible quick fix would be that you actually want: [[String: [String: [String]]]]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your data type declaration:

```
[String: [String : [String]]]
```

Indicates that you have a Dictionary of Dictionaries with the final entries being arrays of strings.

So since all of your dictionaries uses String for keys, using a Int would indeed generate an error.

If you want to extract the Dictionary of arrays, you would need something similar to:

```
// let sourceData: [String: [String: [String]]] ...
guard 
    let myArrayOfDict: [String: [String]] = sourceData["some valid root key"],
    let myArray: [String] = myArrayOfDict["Some other key"]
    else { /* oops, those keys didn't match anything! */ return }

for index in 0..<myArray.count {
    let thisValue = myArray[index]
}

for myString in myArray {
   // myString is a "String"
}
```

Comment: ahhh I feel so dumb. Of Course! Thank you